# How to get my text above my img <div>?

Tags: html, css, image

I have been looking around on stackoverflow to find the answer on my problem but I couldn't find it. The problem is that I have a background img where I want to have text on it. But if I use **postition: absolute;** the text disappears. I also don't want it in my style because I going to use this on different pages with different images.

[Visit problem](http://jsfiddle.net/FlatDesigner/act6uasf/)

HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="http://www.larsdejonge.nl/werk/img/background.jpg" class="begin">
                <h1>Aangenaam Klassiek</h1>
                <h2>Vormgeving & Frontend</h2>
        </div>
</body>
```

And my CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 540px;
    background: #efede7;
}

body {
    background: #efede7;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.3;
}

#header {

}

.begin {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 540px;

}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'ProximaNova', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #c7c7c7;
    text-align: center;
}

h2::after {
    content: '';
    width: 80px;
    display: block;
    background: #272f38;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I hope someone is smarter than me and could figure this out?

**Thanks for already looking into it!**

Comment: Why absolute positioning with an inline image? There's a CSS background-image property.

Comment: Why are you afraid of making a class for each page for each image? Please explain.

Comment: I'm not afraid to make different class everytime but I don't like to have a lot of URL's in my css. It is just because the code don't look really nice if you so 20-30 url's and you do get a lot of code.

Comment: That's a weak reason. You're going to have URLs regardless. You either have more markup in each page or more markup in your CSS. Might as well try and make your code more modular. If you ever have to change an image there's a single one stop destination to do so, your CSS file.

Comment: So you avoid to do it the proper way because it looks ugly? While this is subjective anyway, CSS background images don't leave a gaping hole if the image can't be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you don't want the img in your CSS but if you want that I think you need to find it  out your self. I don't see the big problem using a url in your CSS ore is it just me?

[My solution](http://jsfiddle.net/act6uasf/7/)

You can better use it for the time this now, if you find later something else you can always change it.

HTML Code:

```
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Aangenaam Klassiek</h1>
                <h2>Vormgeving & Frontend</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
</body
```

CCS Code:

```
#header {
    background-image: url(http://www.larsdejonge.nl/werk/img/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 540px;
}
.text {
    padding-top: 150px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'ProximaNova', sans-serif;
    color: #545454;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    letter-spacing: .06em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2::after {
    content: '';
    width: 80px;
    display: block;
    background: #272f38;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think I have to create it myself... But thanks for your answer at least you did it get in the center. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You put your background as image, so it's not just background, but also element with dimension. You should remove your `<img />` and put it as background using CSS.

```
#header {
    background: url('http://www.larsdejonge.nl/werk/img/background.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know, but the problem is that I need to make a lot of classes in my css to change the image and I don't want that. I only want to change the "background.jpg" name to change the image.

Comment: @MyNameIsSwap Why are you afraid of making a class for each image for each page? Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the header image from your html and use CSS properties instead.

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/act6uasf/3/)** which uses this updated CSS snippet:

```
#header {
background-image: url('http://www.larsdejonge.nl/werk/img/background.jpg');
background-size: auto 540px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 540px;
}
```

Background-resize is necessary because your image is way too large.

Comment: Yeah I know, but the problem is that I need to make a lot of classes in my css to change the image and I don't want that. I only want to change the "background.jpg" name to change the image.

Comment: @MyNameIsSwap Why are you afraid of making a class for each image for each page? Please explain.

Comment: If you only want to update the file name, do it in the CSS file. It's the same amount of work. And if you think CSS files with URLs in it are ugly, write inline CSS for your header element.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<IMG>` and use the  img url as background in CCS:

here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/act6uasf/5/

Comment: Yeah I know, but the problem is that I need to make a lot of classes in my css to change the image and I don't want that. I only want to change the "background.jpg" name to change the image.

Comment: @MyNameIsSwap Why are you afraid of making a class for each image for each page? Please explain.

Comment: @MyNameIsSwap, I dont understand what you mean with lots of classes. All you need to do is to add the image to a background css.

Comment: @Obsivus Yeah, but If I make 30 pages I don't want to have 30 times the same CSS in my stylesheet. Just because I use everytime a different image.

Comment: @Obsivus he wants a different header image for each page. To do what we are suggesting he'd have to create a CSS rule for each page. The URLs don't make his CSS "pretty" so he doesn't want to go the CSS route for that specific reason. The OP is allowing his visual preference of a stylesheet to rule his design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to solve this problem with absolute position, you can use my example

http://jsfiddle.net/act6uasf/2/

here to make absolute property work, you just need to add

```
position:relative;
```

to #header, but i recommend you to try solving it with background property.

Comment: But how could I get the text in the center?

Answer (score 0):

`CSS` doesn't prevent you from swapping the image out like you have suggested. I would use a body class.

**HTML**

```
<body class="home"><!-- change this class for each page -->
     <div class="intro">
          <p>
               Hello World!
          </p>
     </div>
</body>
```

Simply change the class on the body tag for each page, i.e. home, about, contact, etc.

**CSS**

```
.home .intro {
     background-image: url('path-to-image.jpg');
}
.about .intro {
     background-image: url('path-to-some-other-image.jpg');
}
```

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hnhdgm12/). Swap the class on the body tag from home to about and click Run to see the difference.